# Ios Check Version of App from Server and Lock User from moving Ahead in App without Upgrading

Tags: ios, version-control

Ios App, need to implement that when the newer version is Available, it show popup and blocks the User to move forward till the time App is not up-to-date.

Please help me out in Blocking App part.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can add a full sized view with addSubview and set user interaction enabled to NO. So you can show your message and your app don't respond to touch events.

Comment: There are several ways: present a modal view that can't be dismissed, show a `UIAlertView` with no buttons, etc. But you should be asking yourself: "__Do I really want to alienate my customers like this?__"

Comment: @neilco - thanks .. Yes the Need is like that to be done.

Comment: Rather than providing an alert with no buttons, perhaps you could open your App Store link when the `UIAlertView` is dismissed?  This will then take the user right to the place where they can update.